# Can not find shortcut menu in Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, menu, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I used to have Settings menu in Eclipse in File tab, but now I don`t see it over there. So, I can not tweak shortcuts the way I need. Help me to find it out, please.

[image]

And there is no shortcut settings in Properties:

[image]

Comment: is now properties....

Comment: I don't recall there ever being a Settings menu for shortcuts in standard Eclipse. Perhaps you were using some additional plugin? Key bindings are in the Preferences in 'General > Keys'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in File -> Properties, or the other main settings menu in eclipse is in Window -> Preferences.